# ubuntu system partition is running out of space after empty my trash, is it normal?

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

I have just delete 4.1 go files from my desktop and after empty the trash. And now my / directory is up now to 100% in use. I cant start anymore Ubuntu. But i have access to safemode to clean the system check fsdisk etc... but how i can free space from my system partition?

any ideas?

UPDATE: my problem wasnt the deleted files, but the real size of / directory. It was out of memory so my ubuntu cannot be started correctly anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/314765/fedora-i-deleted-a-log-file-32gb-big-and-could-not-confirm-it-through-df-comm)

This might be helpful to you.

You can use **lsof** command to check the deleted file is linked with any process or not.

and then kill that process so it will immediately release the space.

Comment: I have solucionated it. thanks for your suggestion. but in my case the deleted files wasnt persistent in process.

Answer (score 0):

You may have moved them to the trash as root, in which case you can delete the files in `/root/.local/share/Trash`.

Comment: ok my files are located at  ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*  there is nothing in root, nothing in my user

Answer (score 0):

I had to run in mode recovery. So i was able to run the root console, and this command help me to find my problem:

```
du -sch /*
```

So i was able to detect the directory which have an anormal size. in my case it was my /opt directory with my apache-tomcat logs with a 4 gigabytes of space! So i can remove easily all the content of this directory.